# Two undefined methods in java

Tags: java

Got started not so long ago, been working on this simple cache memory exercise. I've gotten pretty far (slowly but surely) but now I don't actually know what to do about the problem I have and can't find any solution for myself by just googling etc. like I could before. Also I use Eclipse in case that needs to be said.

"The method clearMemory() is undefined for the type VC"

"The method setText(String) is undefined for the type VC"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class VC {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        final Model model = new Model();
        window.setTitle("Cache memory - 2^n");
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300)); //Bilden som man ska gå efter har 620x320 men sen står det att man ska ha 600x300
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 150));
        final JTextField input1 = new JTextField("0");
        input1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 35));
        inputPanel.add(input1, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
        final JLabel output = new JLabel("Result: ");
        output.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 10));
        outputPanel.add(output, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 50));
        JButton computeButton = new JButton("Compute 2^n");
        computeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 40));
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear memory");
        clearButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 40));
        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        quitButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 40));

        buttonPanel.add(computeButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        buttonPanel.add(clearButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        buttonPanel.add(quitButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        window.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                model.clearMemory();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                model.clearMemory();
                output.setText("Memory cleared.");

            }
        });

        computeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    output.setText("Result:  " + model.compute2Power(Integer.valueOf(input1.getText()).intValue()));
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    output.setText("Input a positive number please!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });



        window.setVisible(true);



    }
}
```

I could probably have figured it out when searching but my knowledge is very limited so if you could explain it to me in pedagogic matter I would be very grateful.

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Model {

    HashMap<Integer, Long> memory;


    public Model() {
        this.memory = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();
    }



    public void clearMemory() {
        this.memory.clear();
    }



    private long computePower (int power) {
        if (power == 0) {
            return 1L;          
        }       
        if (power == 1) {
            return 2L;
    }
        return 2L * computePower (power - 1);
}


    public long compute2Power(int power) {
        if (power < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        Long result = getValueFromMemory(Integer.valueOf(power));
        if (result != null) {
            return result.longValue();
        }
        result = Long.valueOf(computePower(power));
        addValueToMemory(Integer.valueOf(power), result);
        return result.longValue();
    }


    private void addValueToMemory(Integer value, Long result) {
        this.memory.put(value, result);
    }


    private Long getValueFromMemory(Integer value) {
        return (Long)this.memory.get(value);
    }






}
```

Comment: `VC.this.` what you expect this to reference?

Comment: This question would be better if the code was narrowed to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to call:

```
model.clearMemory();
```

and not:

```
VC.this.clearMemory();
```

Since `clearMemory` is a method of your `Model` class.

And `VC.this.setText` should be `output.setText`.

Comment: Fixed my other problem by changing
    VC.this.setText
to
    output.setText

Answer (score 0):

There is no setText(String s) method in VC class. However, there is one in JLabel class. Same thing with clearMemory(). It's an instance method of class Model, so you should create a Model instance and then call it on that instance.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I'm afraid I would need further explaning on how to do this, I'm only a few weeks into this so I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the meaning behind certain things fully. Also have a very limited knowledge of code so far.